# SQL Query With Multiple Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having below mentioned query and it is showing both the result which are in range and also out of range. If P1 is out of range and P2 is in range then it should display P1 out of range value and in P2 it should left blank and in case of P2 if P2 is  out of range and P1 is in range then it should display blank in P1 and value of P1.

```
SELECT  DATEANDTIME,[P1],[P2]
FROM    REPORTDATA
WHERE   [P1] < '85' OR [P1] > '95' OR [P2] < '85' OR [P2] > '95'
```

I tried this query bt didn't worked as expected

Expected output ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sKeH.png)):

```
+ ------------- + ------ + ------ +
| Date and Time | Param1 | Param2 |
|               | Range  | Range  |
|               | 35-50  | 70-80  |
+ ------------- + ------ + ------ +
| 12:35:00      |        | 82     |
| 12.36         |        | 65     |
| 12:37         | 17     | 85     |
| 12:38         | 52     |        |
| 12:39         | 25     |        |
| 14:40         |        | 52     |
+ ------------- + ------ + ------ +
```

Comment: How about, for example: where P1 between 85 and 95?

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I can't understand what you're asking. Could you spice your question up with some punctuation?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Can you please post your input and output also in the question?

Comment: i am having a a table with date and time P1and P2 as columns if either of the columns value is out of range for particular time it should display out of range value in that column and another columns value is in range at that time  then there should blank or hyphen I hopeI am clear by now

Comment: You need to use a case expression which will lets you decide the value returned for a given column. A where clause is used to filter the results which is not what you want here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql Can't possibly help with your query because we have no idea what this range is what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Given my prior attempt and lack of information details this needs better definition and those details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please review for some suggestions.  Please include information regarding ALL the column types and some sample values etc.  Make it easy for us to clearly understand and answer please, avoid making us guess.  For example it MAY be required that we convert a column to another type to properly make a comparison but we have no idea on that.

Comment: Dateandtime Has datatype as datetime and other columns have float as datatype

Comment: Dateandtime Has datatype as datetime and other columns have float as datatype

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are expecting but check below:

```
SELECT  DATEANDTIME,[P1],[P2]
FROM    REPORTDATA
WHERE   ([P1] < '85' OR [P1] > '95') 
   OR ([P2] < '85' OR [P2] > '95')
```

or you can try query with `CASE` :

```
SELECT  DATEANDTIME,[P1],[P2],
    CASE WHEN ([P1] < '85' OR [P1] > '95') OR ([P2] < '85' OR [P2] > '95') THEN 'value out of range'
        ELSE 'value in range'
    END AS INFO
FROM    REPORTDATA
```

TEST giving correct output:

```
declare @p1 int = 86
declare @p2 int = 100

SELECT  getdate(),@p1,@p2,
    CASE WHEN (@p1 < '85' OR @p1 > '95') OR (@p2 < '85' OR @p2 > '95') THEN 'value out of range'
        ELSE 'value in range'
    END AS INFO
```

Comment: No not Working Please Help

Comment: No not Working Please Help

Comment: what you mean by "not working"? Any error or not expected output or no output at all?

Comment: The Logic Which You have provided is not giving expected result as displayed in my post